# pandas group by and summing over integer and timedelta

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sum multiple columns after a group-by with heterogeneous types (integer, float & timedelta)

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: df = pandas.DataFrame({'key': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'val1': range(4), 'val2': [pandas.Timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(4)], 'val3': [0.1 * i for i in range(4)]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   key  val1     val2  val3
0    1     0 00:00:00   0.0
1    1     1 00:00:01   0.1
2    2     2 00:00:02   0.2
3    2     3 00:00:03   0.3
```

In this example, val1 is column of integer, val2 a column of timedeltas and v3 a column of float.

```
In [4]: df.groupby('key').sum()
Out[4]: 
     val1  val3
key            
1       1   0.1
2       5   0.5
```

After summing, the timedelta column has disappeared

```
In [5]: df.groupby('key')['val2'].sum()
Out[5]: 
key
1   00:00:01
2   00:00:05
Name: val2, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Selecting only this column shows that it's summable

```
In [6]: df.groupby('key')['val2', 'val3'].sum()
Out[6]: 
     val3
key      
1     0.1
2     0.5

In [7]: df.groupby('key')['val2', 'val3'].sum()
Out[7]: 
     val3
key      
1     0.1
2     0.5
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns), you can specify which aggregation function you want per column and "force" a function for the val2 column:

```
import numpy as np
...
In [68]: df.groupby('key').agg({'val1': np.sum, 'val2': np.sum, 'val3': np.sum})
Out[68]: 
     val3     val2  val1
key                     
1     0.1 00:00:01     1
2     0.5 00:00:05     5
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you `groupby`-`sum` a DataFrame, pandas doesn't assume that you want to do so for all the columns that are not of the classic numeric types. If you'd have a column of strings, it wouldn't try to apply the sum to them too.

However, since, as you pointed out, you can force the sum for this column, how about

```
import pandas as pd

grouped = df.groupby('key')
pd.concat([grouped.sum(), grouped.val2.sum()], axis=1)
```

Note that you're not repeating the expensive `groupby` op itself.

Comment: Comparison with string sum method is a good point. I put a solution without repeating the groupby